# How to solve APP crash after finish onClick

Tags: android, onclick, crash

I want do some work in the button's onClick listener, but it crashed after onClick() method finished

First, I guess cannot do too much work in the OnClickListener. so I do the same work in a new thread, but crash still exist.

This is the OnClickListener set for the button:

```
stopButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                CloseDevice();
                mTxtStatus.setText("close device successfully!");
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (mBufImage == null) {
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    mTxtReport.setText("capture failed");
                                }
                            });

                            return;
                        }


                        final byte reshapedImg[] = reshape(1);
                        byte centerImage[] =  addCenterPoint(reshapedImg, 256,256);

                        if (centerImage == null) {
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    mTxtStatus.setText("run: locate failed");
                                }
                            });

                            return;
                        } else {
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    mTxtStatus.setText("run:locate success! ");
                                }
                            });

                        }


                        final byte recropedImg [] = recropImg(reshapedImg,256,256);
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Bitmap bitmap = ToolUtils.renderCroppedGreyScaleBitmap(recropedImg, 175, 175);

                                mImgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                            }
                        });


                        double feature [][] = ju.extractFeature(recropedImg,175,175);
                        printarr(feature);
                    }
                }).run();
}
```

In these code. 
`double feature [][] = ju.extractFeature(recropedImg,175,175);`
this function is a native method.and the next line 
`printarr(feature);`
will print the array in logcat. 
The logcat shows the output of printarr() before it crashed. so I am sure onClick() method finished, but it crashed!

I doubt it  crashed in my native method, because the crash happen only if I add the native method. But the backtrace shows it does no matter with my native library:

```
05-24 15:35:37.329 5792-5792/com.example.wangzh.normaltest I/Choreographer: Skipped 65 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-24 15:35:37.337 5792-5810/com.example.wangzh.normaltest A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x40bcf39a3c0aa84c in tid 5810 (RenderThread), pid 5792 (ngzh.normaltest)
05-24 15:35:37.395 5831-5831/? I/crash_dump64: obtaining output fd from tombstoned, type: kDebuggerdTombstone
05-24 15:35:37.396 2752-2752/? I//system/bin/tombstoned: received crash request for pid 5810
05-24 15:35:37.396 5831-5831/? I/crash_dump64: performing dump of process 5792 (target tid = 5810)
05-24 15:35:37.408 5831-5831/? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
05-24 15:35:37.409 5831-5831/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'Android/hikey960/hikey960:9/PQ1A.190105.004/wangzh05142144:userdebug/test-keys'
    Revision: '0'
    ABI: 'arm64'
    pid: 5792, tid: 5810, name: RenderThread  >>> com.example.wangzh.normaltest <<<
    signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x40bcf39a3c0aa84c
        x0  00000070508ccc40  x1  00000070367ed330  x2  0000007050837bb0  x3  000000704a09e838
        x4  0000000000000000  x5  0000000000000000  x6  0000007036293948  x7  0000000044730000
        x8  40bcf39a3c0aa7ec  x9  29ffcb3e9a9df1e0  x10 00000070d2ad7000  x11 0000000000000000
        x12 0000000000000000  x13 00000000000000ff  x14 00000000000007b0  x15 0000000000000000
        x16 00000070d2c5a650  x17 00000070d295b9d0  x18 0000007036295c00  x19 0000007036293948
        x20 0000007050837bb0  x21 00000070367ed330  x22 000000704a0a6780  x23 0000000000000000
        x24 0000000000000000  x25 000000704a09e838  x26 000000703629f588  x27 0000000000003815
        x28 0000000000000000  x29 00000070362938e0
        sp  0000007036293800  lr  00000070d292bfdc  pc  00000070d292c178
05-24 15:35:37.451 5831-5831/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
        #00 pc 000000000046f178  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (_ZL23skpaint_to_grpaint_implP9GrContextRK16GrColorSpaceInfoRK7SkPaintRK8SkMatrixPNSt3__110unique_ptrI19GrFragmentProcessorNSA_14default_deleteISC_EEEEP11SkBlendModeP7GrPaint.llvm.2395171566+592)
        #01 pc 00000000002ada14  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (SkGpuDevice::drawOval(SkRect const&, SkPaint const&)+188)
        #02 pc 000000000049c300  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (SkCanvas::onDrawOval(SkRect const&, SkPaint const&)+392)
        #03 pc 000000000049ea38  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (SkCanvas::drawCircle(float, float, float, SkPaint const&)+104)
        #04 pc 000000000045b0d0  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (SkDrawable::draw(SkCanvas*, SkMatrix const*)+352)
        #05 pc 000000000045b88c  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (SkLiteDL::draw(SkCanvas*) const+196)
        #06 pc 000000000043be7c  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::drawContent(SkCanvas*) const+292)
        #07 pc 000000000043c244  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::forceDraw(SkCanvas*)+252)
        #08 pc 000000000045b004  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (SkDrawable::draw(SkCanvas*, SkMatrix const*)+148)
        #09 pc 000000000045b88c  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (SkLiteDL::draw(SkCanvas*) const+196)
        #10 pc 000000000043be7c  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::drawContent(SkCanvas*) const+292)
        #11 pc 000000000043c244  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::forceDraw(SkCanvas*)+252)
        #12 pc 000000000047e1a4  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::EndReorderBarrierDrawable::onDraw(SkCanvas*)+252)
        #13 pc 000000000045b0d0  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (SkDrawable::draw(SkCanvas*, SkMatrix const*)+352)
        #14 pc 000000000045b88c  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (SkLiteDL::draw(SkCanvas*) const+196)
        #15 pc 000000000043be7c  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::drawContent(SkCanvas*) const+292)
        #16 pc 000000000043c244  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::forceDraw(SkCanvas*)+252)
        #17 pc 000000000045b004  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (SkDrawable::draw(SkCanvas*, SkMatrix const*)+148)
        #18 pc 000000000045b88c  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (SkLiteDL::draw(SkCanvas*) const+196)
        #19 pc 000000000043be7c  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::drawContent(SkCanvas*) const+292)
        #20 pc 000000000043c244  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::forceDraw(SkCanvas*)+252)
        #21 pc 000000000045b004  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (SkDrawable::draw(SkCanvas*, SkMatrix const*)+148)
        #22 pc 000000000045b88c  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (SkLiteDL::draw(SkCanvas*) const+196)
        #23 pc 000000000043be7c  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::drawContent(SkCanvas*) const+292)
        #24 pc 000000000043c244  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::forceDraw(SkCanvas*)+252)
        #25 pc 000000000045b004  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (SkDrawable::draw(SkCanvas*, SkMatrix const*)+148)
        #26 pc 000000000045b88c  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (SkLiteDL::draw(SkCanvas*) const+196)
        #27 pc 000000000043be7c  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::drawContent(SkCanvas*) const+292)
        #28 pc 000000000043c244  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::forceDraw(SkCanvas*)+252)
        #29 pc 000000000045b004  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (SkDrawable::draw(SkCanvas*, SkMatrix const*)+148)
        #30 pc 000000000045b88c  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (SkLiteDL::draw(SkCanvas*) const+196)
        #31 pc 000000000043be7c  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::drawContent(SkCanvas*) const+292)
        #32 pc 000000000043c244  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::forceDraw(SkCanvas*)+252)
        #33 pc 000000000045b004  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (SkDrawable::draw(SkCanvas*, SkMatrix const*)+148)
        #34 pc 000000000045b88c  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (SkLiteDL::draw(SkCanvas*) const+196)
        #35 pc 000000000043be7c  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::drawContent(SkCanvas*) const+292)
        #36 pc 000000000043c244  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::forceDraw(SkCanvas*)+252)
        #37 pc 000000000045b004  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (SkDrawable::draw(SkCanvas*, SkMatrix const*)+148)
        #38 pc 000000000045b88c  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (SkLiteDL::draw(SkCanvas*) const+196)
        #39 pc 000000000043be7c  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::drawContent(SkCanvas*) const+292)
        #40 pc 000000000043c244  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::forceDraw(SkCanvas*)+252)
        #41 pc 000000000045b004  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (SkDrawable::draw(SkCanvas*, SkMatrix const*)+148)
        #42 pc 00000000000fd9a0  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::SkiaPipeline::renderFrameImpl(android::uirenderer::LayerUpdateQueue const&, SkRect const&, std::__1::vector<android::sp<android::uirenderer::RenderNode>, std::__1::allocator<android::sp<android::uirenderer::RenderNode>>> const&, bool, bool, android::uirenderer::Rect const&, SkCanvas*)+424)
        #43 pc 00000000004803c8  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::SkiaPipeline::renderFrame(android::uirenderer::LayerUpdateQueue const&, SkRect const&, std::__1::vector<android::sp<android::uirenderer::RenderNode>, std::__1::allocator<android::sp<android::uirenderer::RenderNode>>> const&, bool, bool, android::uirenderer::Rect const&, sk_sp<SkSurface>)+136)
        #44 pc 000000000047f5d4  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::SkiaOpenGLPipeline::draw(android::uirenderer::renderthread::Frame const&, SkRect const&, SkRect const&, android::uirenderer::FrameBuilder::LightGeometry const&, android::uirenderer::LayerUpdateQueue*, android::uirenderer::Rect const&, bool, bool, android::uirenderer::BakedOpRenderer::LightInfo const&, std::__1::vector<android::sp<android::uirenderer::RenderNode>, std::__1::allocator<android::sp<android::uirenderer::Re
        #45 pc 0000000000108028  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::CanvasContext::draw()+192)
        #46 pc 00000000004844dc  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (_ZNSt3__110__function6__funcIZN7android10uirenderer12renderthread13DrawFrameTask11postAndWaitEvE3$_0NS_9allocatorIS6_EEFvvEEclEv$c303f2d2360db58ed70a2d0ac7ed911b+644)
        #47 pc 000000000043adc8  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::WorkQueue::process()+168)
        #48 pc 000000000011575c  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::RenderThread::threadLoop()+244)
        #49 pc 000000000000fb80  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+280)
        #50 pc 0000000000083194  /system/lib64/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+36)
        #51 pc 00000000000233bc  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+68)
05-24 15:35:37.834 2752-2752/? E//system/bin/tombstoned: Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_15
```

Could anyone can give some advice? Anything are appreciated! Thank you In advance.

Comment: Could you update the answer with the crash stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

You need to start you thread via **start()** method, not run(), because run() just invokes the runnable in the sâme thread so it blocks the main thread:

```
stopButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                CloseDevice();
                mTxtStatus.setText("close device successfully!");
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (mBufImage == null) {
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    mTxtReport.setText("capture failed");
                                }
                            });

                            return;
                        }


                        final byte reshapedImg[] = reshape(1);
                        byte centerImage[] =  addCenterPoint(reshapedImg, 256,256);

                        if (centerImage == null) {
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    mTxtStatus.setText("run: locate failed");
                                }
                            });

                            return;
                        } else {
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    mTxtStatus.setText("run:locate success! ");
                                }
                            });

                        }


                        final byte recropedImg [] = recropImg(reshapedImg,256,256);
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Bitmap bitmap = ToolUtils.renderCroppedGreyScaleBitmap(recropedImg, 175, 175);

                                mImgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                            }
                        });


                        double feature [][] = ju.extractFeature(recropedImg,175,175);
                        printarr(feature);
                    }
                }).start();
}
```

Comment: Yes, Thank you! I didn't notice this point. I think this is the reason why it shows this warning: >Skipped 65 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread. This warning disappear after do this change. but the crash still exists

Comment: Hello, after doing what you said, the crash information in the logcat became more clear, so I find it indeed crash in my native library. Now, I find the crash line using addr2line and solve this problem. Thank you very much!